xamarin forms, listview itemtemplate - change binding based on other values in bindingsource row
Currently, I have a Xamarin project and I populate a listview using itemsource.
<Label Text="{Binding BBName, Converter={StaticResource valConv}, ConverterParameter='bbnamevssym'}" TextColor="{StaticResource textColorBlack}" VerticalTextAlignment="End" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14"/>

I want to change this... I basically want to populate this label based on some of the other fields in the same row of data.  for example, I want to look at 3 columns.
name,
symbol,
id
if id = yes then use name, if not use symbol.
I was trying to use the converter, but I don't see how to bring in other fields.  can someone point me in the right direction?
this is my ivalueconverter
public class ValueConverters : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
        if (parameter.ToString() == "bbnamevssym")
        {
            var x1 = 1;
            return "hi";
        }

this is how i defined my listview
   <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Header="{Binding}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TradesSectorGrouped}"

in the viewmodel I have defined the itemsource as such
class ManagerSectorTradesPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public ObservableCollection<Trade> TradesSectorGrouped { get; set; }


pass the entire object into an IValueConverter

sorry, how do you do that?  I tried this but it is returning null in ivalueconverter... <Label Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource valConv}, ConverterParameter='bbnamevssym'}"

without seeing your converter code I can't say what the problem might be

I added my ivalueconverter above... is that what you mean?  object value is coming back as null

you old posted the signature, not the code.  And what type is the input object?

i added to my original post.  The input object is a custom observable collection.  am I passing in the binding correctly?

The input object for the converter would be a singled Trade object, wouldn't it?  And your converter is not even looking at the input object.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
